# If I have a joint normal prior distribution on $(x,y)$ with $x,y$ each normal, can I construct a closed form joint distribution?

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

If I have a joint normal prior distribution on $(x,y)$ where $x \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 4)$ and $y \sim \mathcal{N}(10, 100)$, and $corr(x,y) = 0.5$, what would be a closed form distribution I can use? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming 4 and 100 are the variances for $x$ and $y$ respectively.

$$ \left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right) \sim N\left( \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 10 \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 4 & \sqrt{4\times 100}\times 0.5 \\ \sqrt{4\times 100}\times 0.5 & 100 \end{array} \right] \right) $$